# history.push changes URL but does not render any component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, and I am trying to use useHistory in order to link my pages. However, only the URL is changing, and the page does not reload or change (I have a blank page). What am I missing ?

App.tsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";


import Home from './pages/Home';
import OrganizerHome from './pages/organizer/accueilOrganizer'
import HomeContact from './pages/contact/accueilContact'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#87cefa'
        }
    }
});


function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                        <Route exact path="/organizer" component={OrganizerHome}/>
                        <Route exact path="/contact" component={HomeContact}/>
                    </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

How I use useHistory in all my files (ex : accueilOrganizer.tsx) :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Home() {
   const history = useHistory();
   
   return (
      <div>
         <Button onClick={() => history.push("/organizer")}>Organizer</Button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

The code for `<OrganizerHome />` is quite simple, as I wanted to test history.push :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
    Today,
} from '@material-ui/icons';
import {
    Button,
    Theme,
    createStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    home: {
        paddingTop: '5em',
    },
}));

export default function OrganizerHome() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const classes= useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.home}>
            <p>Pour voir le calendrier, c'est par ici !</p>
            <Button onClick={() => history.push('/organizer/essai')}><Today /></Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you have Router in your ReactDom.render as well? If yes then remove Router from App.jsx file

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem but you're using a component named `<Button />` without importing it at least in your example.

Comment: Can you also share the code in your `<OrganizerHome />` component?

Comment: I don't have a Router in ReactDom.render and I did import ```<Button />``` (I was trying to show what I do usually, and I forgot to put ot, sorry...).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
function Home(props) {
  
    const sendData = () => {
        props.history.push({
            pathname: '/organizer',
            // If you want to push somedata then you send through state
            state: {
                date: "Data"
            }
        });
    };
   
   return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={sendData}>Organizer</button>
      </div>
   )
}


export default Home(InputData);
```

then in organization section you can get `state` date like this `**props.location.state.date**`